# Вывести желаемое поле из Базы Данных Django

Tags: python, django

Есть главная страница кулинарного сайта, там есть раздел "Рекоммендуемые" , а там 6 рецептов.

В базе данных есть табличка "Рецепты" с вот такими полями:

```py
class Recipes(models.Model):
    recipe_name = models.CharField('Имя рецепта', max_length=50)
    intro = models.CharField('Анонс', max_length=250)
    full_text = models.TextField('Рецепт')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.recipe_name
```

Теперь хочу чтобы в рекоммендациях, внизу картинки каждого рецепта показывалась поле Intro к каждому соответствуещему рецепту, например к первому рецепту стояла поле intro первого рецепта из БД

Views.py пока что так:

```py
def index(request):
    recipes = Recipes.objects.order_by('-intro')

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'Recipes':recipes})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через точку можно обратиться к нужному полю

```
{% for recipe in Recipes %}
    {{ recipe.recipe_name }}
    {{ recipe.intro }}
    {{ recipe.full_text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не особо понял, но возможно это решение вам подойдет:

```html
{% for recipe in Recipes %}
    {{ recipe.recipe_name }}
    {{ recipe.intro }}
{% endfor %}
```